# Rewrite foreach as array_map

Tags: php, loops, foreach, array-map

Super quick question: Can I rewrite the following small piece of code:

```
foreach ($countries as $c => $country) {
    $stats[$c] = count($country);
}
```

using `array_map`? Ie something like:

```
$stats = array_map('count', $countries);
```

but then, I also want to associate each record of `$stats` to the key of the corresponding record of `$countries`! Thanks in advance for any reply!

Comment: I haven't run it, but that looks like it would work. `array_map` preserves keys, so you should end up with the same keys from `$countries`. If you don't have an easy way to test ideas like this in your project, you can try running them in one of the various online sandboxes like 3v4l.org.

Comment: Duh! You're right! It works like a charm! How stupid can I be... LOL Thanks a lot for your suggestion!

Comment: I can totally run tests like this in my project. I didn't even _bother_ trying this because I thought it wouldn't run the way I'd want it to, because I didn't know `array_map` preserves the original keys! So thanks again for your suggestion... Sometimes all that's needed is a little push from somebody...

Comment: You're welcome! If you're ever in doubt about that kind of thing, the PHP docs for all the array functions will say whether or not keys are preserved in their "return values" sections.

Comment: I know! php.net is like a Holy Grail to me... But, as I said, I considered it highly unlikely to work out of the box, so I didn't even bother trying or even looking it up! I was miserably wrong!

Comment: @FayeD.: note you can self-answer your question, which will be of value to others, especially if you link to and quote the relevant section of the PHP manual on [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map#refsect1-function.array-map-returnvalues).